# Set a django object property through a subquery

Tags: django, django-orm

I have an object of type `Foo` with a ForeignKey to a `Bar`. `Bar` has a property called `slug`.

I can do

```
myfoo.bar = Bar.objects.get(slug='123')
```

But this would add an extra query. Is it possible to have Django generate the assignment as a sub-query within the update?

i.e. generate SQL similar to:

```
UPDATE myfoo SET bar_id = (select id from bar where slug = '123')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Django [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expression:

```python
from django.db.models import Subquery

# create the "SELECT id FROM bar WHERE slug = '123' LIMIT 1" subquery
subquery = Bar.objects.filter(slug='123')[:1]
# update only the correct foo object with this subquery
Foo.objects.filter(pk=myfoo.pk).update(bar=Subquery(subquery))
# refresh the variable so that `myfoo.bar` is correct
myfoo.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do it through simple assignment? I.e., I am setting several properties (including a set property) and I'd like to do `foo.a=1; foo.b=2; foo.c=[c,d,e]; foo.bar=Subquery(...)`. Though if I can do `update(a=...,c=[...])` it could work.

Comment: @Tordek Yes you have to use `update` with multiple parameters. Otherwise, you will end up with a lot of queries.